# CSS: Make an image in the exact middle of the page

Tags: css, alignment, centering

I would like to make an image center in the exact middle of the page, so it's centered vertical and horizontal! Can I do that with a 765x741? Thanks!

Comment: Did you search the web at all? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Comment: Yes! What have you tried already? Have you tried or looked at [any of these questions (and their answers)](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+css+html+center+horizontal+vertical)?

Comment: Is there anything else on the page?

Comment: no there is only that image. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of cause you can create a static class in CSS like suggested already:

```
.centerPic
{
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left:-382px; /* Static value */
    margin-top:-370px; /* Static value */
}
```

But this approach ***limits your use of other pictures of different sizes***. I suggest you set the margin-left and margin-top properties depending on your picture sizes in *dynamic javascript instead*:

```
function SetCenterStyle (objPic)
{
    objPic.className = "centerPic";
    objPic.style.marginLeft = ( -1 * ( parseInt(objPic.width) / 2 ) ) + "px";
    objPic.style.marginTop = ( -1 * ( parseInt(objPic.height) / 2 ) ) + "px";
}
```

(You can then of cause omit the margin-left and margin-top settings in the centerPic class)

Answer (score 1):

Create css class for the image.

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!  The following css will do it

```
.centerImg
{
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-382px /*half the width*/
    margin-top:-370px /*half the height*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the margin: auto auto;

I thinks it's the best way

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
img.class-name{

    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;  
}
```